# Show newest post in ASC order in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to get newest post
which is in result string display like

```
12th Jul 2015
24th Mar 2015
18th Jan 2015
```

I want to display it like

```
18th Jan 2015
24th Mar 2015
12th Jul 2015
```

I have query string

```
<?php query_posts(array( 'cat' => '17', 'orderby' => 'post_date', 'order' => 'DESC', 'posts_per_page' => 3 ) ); ?>
```

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Yes, but ASC gives me oldest post and i want newest 3 with ascending order, and i have tried much before asking the question. :)

Comment: I guess you need to read this https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts

Comment: Descending means newest first, or the biggest number first, then falling down to older and older. so to achieve what you want to use ASC (ascending). If that simply does not work, its more to youre code thats failing

Comment: That link will also show you that you shouldn't use `query_posts()` basically ever.

Comment: I am trying to solve my problem using that link, And @oBo that query is working but i want latest 3 posts in ascending order while query resulting latest 3 posts in descending.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this works:

```
<?php
$myposts = get_posts('cat=3&showposts=3');
if ($myposts) {
$uc=array();
  foreach ($myposts as $mypost) {
    $uc[]=$mypost->ID;
    }
  }
    $args=array(
      'post__in' => $uc,
      'orderby' => 'post_date',
      'order' => 'ASC',
      'posts_per_page' => 3,
      'caller_get_posts' => 1
    );
    $my_query = new WP_Query($args);
    if( $my_query->have_posts() ) {
      echo 'Category 3, lastest posts, sorted oldest to newest';
      while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post(); ?>
        <p><small><?php the_time('m.d.y') ?> </small><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="Permanent Link to <?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></p>
       <?php
      endwhile;
    } //if ($my_query)
  wp_reset_query();  // Restore global post data stomped by the_post().
?>
```